# What's the best way to have a dynamic JTable whose data updates itself with changes in database table?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sqlite, jtable

I'm having 2 `JFrames` (both work independently), but use the same database table. One inserts data in to the table while the other reads it. 
How can I have a `jTable` in one `JFrame` which continuously polls for changes / updates (as new data is inserted) in the database and updates itself with these changes?
I don't know much about threads but can threads help? By starting a thread which performs `SELECT * FROM TABLE` operation and using this data to update the `tablemodel`?

Comment: `which continuously polls for changes / updates (as new data is inserted) in the database and updates itself with these changes?` == util.Timer that invoke SwingWorker periodicaly, `using this data to update the tablemodel?` == yes

Comment: @mKorbel if possible , can you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Also consider [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)